# How many registers are there in 8086/8088?

Tags: x86, cpu, x86-16, cpu-registers, microprocessors

I took Computer Architecture course and I understood that processor has 32 registers each of 32 bit. Now I am studying computer architecture course in which I read that 8086 has [8  registers only](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086). But the book I read and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20111227070256/http://www.compeng.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_registers/8086_registers.html) website shows many registers. I am getting confused about the registers in 8086 and 8088. Please help me out.

### NOTE:

I have a good understanding of different register sizes in different processors. I am just getting confused in the number of registers.

Comment: you should invest in a more modern computer :p

Comment: But the basics are almost same for all much as I know :)

Comment: 8086 is missing 32-bit protected mode which makes it convenient to use a flat memory model, and 32-bit addressing is more orthogonal (fewer special registers).  32-bit user-space code is quite simple; the OS takes care of all the extra complexity of GDT, segmentation, and paging.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The 8086 and 8088 are 16 bit processors - their registers are each 16 bits in width.  (A few instructions treat the combination of DX and AX as a 32 bit integer, like div input and mul output.)

Note that the 8086 has 16 bit data bus; the 8088 has an 8 bit data bus.  (So loading/storing a 16-bit word takes 2 bus cycles.  Addresses are still 20-bit for both.)

The [site you linked](https://web.archive.org/web/20111227070256/http://www.compeng.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_registers/8086_registers.html) is accurate; the following is a copy/paste from it with a couple light edits:

> **GENERAL PURPOSE REGISTERS**
>
> 8086 CPU has 8 general purpose registers, each register has its own
> name:
>
> AX - the accumulator register (divided into AH / AL):
>
> ```
> Generates shortest machine code: short-form encodings exist
> Arithmetic, logic and data transfer
> One number must be in AL or AX
> Multiplication & Division
> Input & Output
> ```
>
> BX - the base address register (divided into BH / BL).
>
> ```
> Offset address relative to DS by default   CX - the count register (divided into CH / CL):
>
> The LOOP instruction uses it implicitly as a counter
> Repetitive operations on strings with the REP command
> Count (in CL) of bits to shift and rotate   DX - the data register (divided into DH / DL):
>
> DX:AX concatenated into 32-bit register for some MUL and DIV operations
> Specifying ports in some IN and OUT operations   SI - source index register:
>
> Can be used for pointer addressing of data
> Used as source in some string processing instructions
> Offset address relative to DS by default   DI - destination index register:
>
> Can be used for pointer addressing of data
> Used as destination in some string processing instructions as ES:DI
> Offset address relative to DS outside of string instructions
> ```
>
> BP - base pointer:
>
> ```
> Primarily used to access parameters and locals on the stack
> Offset address relative to SS
> ```
>
> SP - stack pointer:
>
> ```
> Always points to top item on the stack
> Offset address relative to SS (but can't be used in 16-bit addressing modes)
> Should always points to word (byte at even address)
> An empty stack will have SP = FFFEh
> ```
>
> **SEGMENT REGISTERS**
>
> - CS - points at the segment containing the current program.
> - DS - generally points at segment where variables are defined.
> - ES - extra segment register, it's up to a coder to define its usage.
> - SS - points at the segment containing the stack.
>
> Although it is possible to store any data in the segment registers,
> this is never a good idea. The segment registers have a very special
> purpose - pointing at accessible blocks of memory.
>
> Segment registers work together with general purpose register to
> access any memory value. For example if we would like to access memory
> at the physical address 12345h (hexadecimal), we could set the DS =
> 1230h and SI = 0045h. This way we can form 20-bit linear addresses,
> instead of just 16 bit  with a single register.  (This applies in real
> mode; in protected mode segmentation is different.)
>
> The CPU makes a calculation of the physical address by multiplying the
> segment register by 10h and adding the general purpose register to it
> (1230h * 10h + 45h = 12345h):
>
> The address formed with 2 registers is called an effective address.
> By default BX, SI and DI registers work with DS segment register;   BP
> and SP work with SS segment register.   Other general purpose
> registers cannot form an effective address.   Also, although BX can
> form an effective address, BH and BL cannot.
>
> **SPECIAL PURPOSE REGISTERS**
>
> IP - the instruction pointer:
>
> ```
> Always points to next instruction to be executed
> Offset address relative to CS
> ```
>
> IP register always works together with CS segment register and it
> points to currently executing instruction.
>
> **FLAGS  REGISTER**
>
> Flags Register - determines the current state of the processor. They
> are modified automatically by CPU after mathematical operations, this
> allows to determine the type of the result, and to determine
> conditions to transfer control to other parts of the program.
> Generally you cannot access FLAGS directly, except via `pushf`/`popf`.  Some special instructions exist to set/clear some of the specific bits.
>
> The status / condition-code bits in [FLAGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) are:
>
> - Carry Flag (CF) - this flag is set to 1 when there is an unsigned
>   overflow. For example when you add bytes 255 + 1 (result is not in
>   range 0...255). When there is no overflow this flag is set to 0.
> - Parity Flag (PF) - this flag is set to 1 when there is even number of one bits in (the low 8 bits of a) result, and to 0 when there is odd number of one bits.
> - Auxiliary Flag (AF) - set to 1 when there is an unsigned overflow (carry-out) for low nibble (4 bits).
> - Zero Flag (ZF) - set to 1 when result is zero. For non-zero result this flag is set to 0.
> - Sign Flag (SF) - set to 1 when result is
>   negative. When result is positive it is set to 0. (This flag takes the value of the most significant bit.)
> - Trap Flag (TF) - Used for
>   on-chip debugging.
> - Interrupt enable Flag (IF) - when this flag is set to 1 CPU reacts to interrupts from external devices.
> - Direction Flag (DF) - this
>   flag is used by some instructions to process arrays.  When this flag
>   is set to 0 the processing is done forward, when this flag is set to 1
>   the processing is done backward.
> - Overflow Flag (OF) - set to 1
>   when there is a signed overflow. For example, when you add bytes 100 + 50 (result is not in range -128...127).

Answer (score 5):

The 8086 has 14 16 bits registers. AX, BX, CX, DX, SI, DI, BP, SP, CS, DS, SS, ES, IP and the flags register. The last two are only accessed indirectly.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: Huh? According to [sources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/x86_memory_segmentation), the 80386 was the first processor in this line with FS and GS registers, and so it would be incorrect to include them in a list of the 8086 registers.

Comment: @DavidCary : I apologise, must've been drunk. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 4):

> I took Computer Architecture course and I understood that processor
>   has 32 registers each of 32 bit.

This doesn't answer your question, but if you want to communicate with annother engineer, you have to use the proper language. Saying "a (some) processor has 32 registers that are 32 bits in size" won't get you anywhere, there are countless numbers of processors.

> The 8086 had eight (more or less general) 16-bit registers including
>   the stack pointer, but excluding the instruction pointer, flag
>   register and segment registers. Four of them, AX, BX, CX, DX, could
>   also be accessed as twice as many 8-bit registers (see figure) while
>   the other four, BP, SI, DI, SP, were 16-bit only.

I'm assuming the confusion comes from this sentence on the Wikipedia. Both of the sources you read are right. There are 8 general purpouse registers (in the article it's noted as "more or less general", i've no idea who could write that), they are: AX BX CX DX and SI DI BP SP. There are also segment registers, special purpouse registers and a flag register (which are noted after the "excluding" word, which, i'm guessing, is suppoused to be read as "there are registers, there's 8 of them if you exclude these 3 groups", it's vague).

The issue is in the wording. The quoted sentence is confusing and i can see where your question is comming from. It never hurts to ask, but you should understand that Wikipedia is not a reliable source of knowledge, if you're ever confused, just pick up a book.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why everyone else also provides links from Wikipedia to prove their answers or to quote anything.

Answer (score 2):

Computer architecture books often use MIPS as example because it's rather simple and educational. MIPS has 32 registers but this does **not** mean that other 32-bit architectures also have 32 registers. *32-bit* here only means that the computer has [32-bit address/32-bit integer registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29#Uses_of_words). It's not related to the number of registers in any way.

ARM, the most popular 32-bit architecture, has 16 registers (although ARMv8 64-bit doubled this number to 32). Many other 32-bit architectures also have register number other than 32 such as Motoroka 68k and SuperH v2/3/4, all have 16 registers. For the list of architectures look at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_CPU_architectures#Instruction_sets). You see, 64-bit architectures rarely have 64 registers, as that'll increase the register file size a lot, and makes context switch worse. Most of them have 32 registers.

x86, being backward compatible with 8086 many decades ago, has only 8 visible integer registers. But in fact x86 CPUs nowadays have hundreds of registers inside and use [register renaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming) to overcome the limit in number of registers.

Comment: Register renaming doesn't let you avoid spill/reload when you have more than 6 or 7 things to keep "up in the air" at once.  It does avoid the need for software pipelining, but it's not a fully replacement.  That's why AMD64 doubled the number of *architectural* integer registers, even though earlier AMD CPUs already did register renaming onto a larger physical register file.