# How many registers are used when a variable is declared using register storage class?

Tags: c, cpu-registers, storage-class-specifier

My question is simply, how many registers will a C compiler use for a variable declared using `register` storage class as :
`register int a`. I have read this answer [How many register and what kind of register are available for the storage class REGISTER in c language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426676/how-many-register-and-what-kind-of-register-are-available-for-the-storage-class) but could not understand much. I know it can be implementation dependent, but then this registers are limited, so when would the compiler ignore the declaration or will it generate an error?

Comment: An int will generally fit in a register, but the `register` keyword probably won't achieve anything.

Comment: You shouldn't use the register keyword anymore. Modern compilers are smart enough to choose what variable to put in registers automaticly.

Comment: "*when would the compiler ignore the declaration*" <- the safe assumption here is: **always**. As already said, this storage class is an obsolete feature of C.

Comment: @litelite I don't use it anyway. I am just curious.

Comment: Assume that the compiler will ignore your hint; it knows better than you when to put variables into registers.

Comment: Note: Keyword `register` retains a use in modern C.  Code like `register int a; ... int *b = &a;` is a constraint violation.If this is use or not - meh?  Otherwise only select compilers benefit with use of `register` and a number of compiles are prevented from optimization due to `register`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C11 still supports `register`:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class
>   specifier register suggests that access to the object be as fast as
>   possible. The extent to which such suggestions are effective is
>   implementation-defined.

In notes:

> The implementation may treat any register declaration simply as an
>   auto declaration.

So how many registers will be used? One possible answer is 'none' because the keyword may be ignored.

That said, in practice it's very rare for an implementation on any modern platform to define `int`with a width that is wider than width of a typical platform 'word'. So if an implementation respects `register int a;` it's unlikely `register int a` will be allocated to more than one register and `register int a` may be 0,1 or 2 registers.

Of course on some hardware not all registers are the same size and sometimes different instructions treat registers as separate or joined. How many registers may not be meaningful.

As others point out use of the keyword is widely discouraged in C. Indeed its meaning now removed from C++ (though the keyword retained as reserved).

I think that would be draconian in C which still looks to micro-controller environments where programmers come closest to want to dictate such details.

All that said 'back in the day' (25 years ago) I worked with a compiler that ignored `register` but allocated the first 2 (I think) declared variables used as loop counters to registers and in the case in question the third loop in the function was longest and performance noticeably improved by declaring the big loop index first.

That all seems a very long time ago and no one should take it as the modern experience.

Comment: `but allocated the first 2 (I think) declared variables used as loop counters to registers` - it is dynamic and depends on the optimisation level, and optimisation algorithms in the particular compiler. For example gcc compiler will choose which variables is better to keep in memory and which ones in the registers, and order of declaration is ignored.. The numbers of the general use registers is much larger in the RISC machines like AVR or ARM.

Comment: Even when doing microcontroller programming, the `register` keyword doesn't make much sense. Because many microcontrollers have quite few CPU registers, that are needed for things like local variables, temporary storage and function parameter passing. If some microcontroller programmer runs around and spams `register` all over, they are more likely to mess up the optimal program flow than to make the program go any faster.

Comment: @PeterJ. Maybe it wasn't clear. I'm half remembering a specific compiler I used about 25 years ago. I don't recall the details but it did use the first few declarations and it was clear in the assembler and performance that it did so. I am in no way suggesting anyone use that trick. I doubt there's an extant compiler working like that. May have been Borland or Watcom in the early 90s.

Comment: @Lundin - nowadays it is almost a forgotten feature. But some time ago many AVR programers had to use them if the latency of the interrupt routine was an issue. I personally did not use the register bindings for years.

Comment: @Persixty  `I used about 25 years ago` completely different code generation than now :). Now the micro optimisations can cause the right opposite effect than expected

Comment: @PeterJAhh! "ObI Wan" I ain't heard that name in along time.. This is old stuff. In fact the limitation was quite poor optimization because as I recall the loops in question were disjoint and it could have used them all as registers with a bit of shuffling but I think it was C89 and all variables were declared at the top and the compiler clearly couldn't work out where were accessed later or could be overwritten.

Comment: @PeterJ Hence my prefixing it all with 'back in the day'. That means ancient history from times of yore that young 'uns might want to hear. When men were real men and women were real women and small furry creatures from Alpha-Centuri were real small furry creatures from Alpha-Centuri.

Answer (score 0):

The `register` is a suggestion for the compiler to keep the variable in the register if possible. But the modern compilers just ignore it. So the answering your question - it can be zero or more  the compiler will decide depending on the optimisation options used.

Some compilers have special form of binging variables to the register.

gcc version

```
       register int *foo asm ("r12");
```

it can be global or local binding.

global binding: the register variable is kept in the register for the whole program execution, the register is taken out form the compiler register pool. It can make compiler optimisations less effective.

local binding: the register variable is tied to the register only in the scope of the function.

But it is not guaranteed that the library routines which were compiled without `-ffixed-reg` option will keep this register unaffected. Same is with the `setjump` & `longjump` as restoring of the content of registers is machine specific.

Deep understanding of the machine code generation is required to use it efficiently. Rarely used nowadays. Use examples - reducing latency in response to the interrupt requests and similar.